# I always get an error on VS code when I code in c

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code

I have just started coding in c on my MacBook Air(m1). But whenever I code anything on VS code it throws the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have installed all the extensions and the clang as well but it always shows this error. I am new to coding and have very little idea about it.

Comment: If you are coding in C, why the C++ tag?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to create an `int main()` function. Or perhaps you did not modify your `tasks.json` file in the way the documentation tells you to support more than one source file. The default behavior is to build only the active file into an executable ignoring all other files in the folder. The default makes it easier to build simple one source file applications and test without having to create a new project or folder for each.

Comment: @crashmstr sorry, thought they were similar..